# Composing a sequence of functions that return future

Tags: scala, future

I am looking for an elegant way of composing a sequence of functions that return `Future`. I.e., for a sequence of `(f1, f2, ..., f_n)`, each function being of type `T=>Future[T]`, I want to produce a new function, `g`, where `g(x) = f_n(...f2(f1(x))...)`.

My implementation is as follows:

```
  def doInOrder[T] (fs : (T => Future[T])*)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext): T=>Future[T] = {
    (t:T) => {
      fs.reduceLeft((future1: T=>Future[T], future2: T=>Future[T]) =>
        (arg:T) => future1(arg).flatMap((arg2:T) => future2(arg2))
      )(t)
    }
  }
```

This works, as far as I can tell. The solution seems a little convoluted though, with a number of nested lambdas. **Can it be simplified?**

The problem comes from Horstmann's book, *Scala for the impatient*, which asks to

> Write a function `doInOrder` that, given two functions `f: T =>
>   Future[U]` and `g: U
>   => Future[V]`, produces a function `T => Future[U]` that, for a given t, eventually yields `g(f(t))`

and then to:

> Repeat the preceding exercise for any sequence of functions of type `T
>   => Future[T]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
def doInOrder[T] (fs : (T => Future[T])*)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext): T=>Future[T] = {
    t => fs.foldLeft(Future.successful(t))((acc, f) => acc.flatMap(f))
  }
```